# Delete Data From Table of Specific Month

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

In My Table, I Have a Column Which Stores the Date. I am Passing Month Number as an argument to a stored Procedure.

I would like to delete all entries of that month from table.

Is it Possible....??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is your answer :

```
delete from yourtable where month(YourDatetimeColumn) = 5 -- for example 'may'
```

OR

```
delete from yourtable where datepart(mm,YourDatetimeColumn) = 5 -- for example 'may'
```

Note : replace `5` with your input parameter. This will not consider the `year` part of your date so if it is may-2014 or may-2015, all will be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with SQL server versions, but youre tagged as 2005.

If there is issues with `month()` then you can also use;

```
delete from your_table where datepart(month, table_datefield) = @procedure_argument_month
```

But as in other answer, this will delete all fields which month is as you provided, as you described, not minding the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from TABLE_NAME
where DATEPART(mm,ColumnName) = @MONTH_PARAMETER
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you :

```
delete from [tablename] 
where DATEPART(month,[datecolumn]) = @inputDigit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in given Query pass your month in Digit of which month you want to delete the data.

```
Delete from tbl_xyz where DATEPART(mm, clm_CreatedTime) = @Month
```